# Handling Opening Time and Closing Time

Tags: php, if-statement

Let say store open at 13:00 but customer can allow to make orders after 16:00 (standard time)

The if statement doesnt seem to work properly as expected, how to fix it?

Code:

```
if ((date('H:i') >= '16:00') && ($data[$key]['opentime'] >= '16:00')) {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 1;
} else {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 0;
}
```

Possible Opentime:

```
$data[$key]['opentime']
// Opentime = 12:30
// Opentime = 14:00
// Opentime = 16:00
// Opentime = 16:30
// Opentime = 17:00
```

Also customer can not make order after 23:30 but should check with `$data[$key]['closetime']` (eg: 20:00, 21:00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't know '10:00' is a time. To PHP, '10:00' is just text.

It's like asking PHP if 'abcfg' is larger than 'jg'.

If you know you'll be dealing with hours only, simply use a number to represent an hour. Your code would look like:

```
$h1 = (int) date('H');
$h2 = (int) $data[$key]['opentime']; // anything after ':' is ignored
if (($h1 >= 16) && ($h2 >= 16)) {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 1;
} else {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but open time maybe 14:30 (I need the minutues included)

Comment: It is 50% working but if $data[$key]['opentime'] is 16:00 and order time is 13:00 then  $data[$key]['open'] should be 0...

Answer (score 3):

Well, maybe this little function will help you:

```
function HourMinuteToDecimal($hour_minute)
{
    $t = explode(':', $hour_minute);
    return $t[0]*60+$t[1];
}
```

edit:
if I understand your code logic correct, then:

```
if (HourMinuteToDecimal($data[$key]['opentime']) > HourMinuteToDecimal(date('H:i'))) {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 1;
} else {
    $data[$key]['open'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: The order time missing on your if statement... Example if $data[$key]['opentime'] is 16:00 and ordertime is 13:00 then $data[$key]['open'] should be 0..

Comment: @user622378 well, I hope you can fix it now :)

Comment: @OZ_ HourMinuteToDecimal function does not work for 24 hours Time, Example... 00:00, 01:30 . How to fix this issue?

Comment: To understand where I am coming from, check nowtime between opentime and closetime. OpenTime might be 16:00 and 02:00 next day morning. I am trying to solve this issue.

Comment: @user622378 no, should be `closed`. Without any digits even - `open` it's when $nowTime less than $closeTime. To solve this issue, check, if $openTime is less than $closeTime, and add 12 hours to close time in this case. `if ($closeTime < $openTime) $closeTime = $openTime + 720;` (720 is 12*60)

Answer (score 1):

you should convert the string '16:00' to date (not the actual date to string) and do the comparison between 2 date values.